# Converting String to Date using Talend Open Studio

Tags: java, type-conversion, talend

I'm trying to convert this kind of date "31/01/2014" to this format "31-01-2014", I tried to use TalendDate.parseDate("dd/MM/yyyy",row.date)... but does't work.

This is the error:

At least job "payment" has a compile errors, please fix and export again.
Error Line: 1709
Detail Message: The method parseDate(String, String) in the type TalendDate is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date)
There may be some other errors caused by JVM compatibility. Make sure your JVM setup is similar to the studio.

Can sameone help me?

Thanks! :D

Comment: I think the clue is in the error message. Your arg `row.date` is already a `Date`, while the function is expecting a string to parse.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your goal is without seeing more code. Perhaps instead of converting a string to a date, what you really need is to convert a date to a string of a particular format?